# How to identify the next running javascript statement or function entry point?

Tags: javascript, debugging

In many website pages, there are a lot of javascript codes to support the functionalities. The programmer can attach the event on the element via many methods. They can add the event directly in the element definition like

```
<input type="button" onclick="dosomething();">
```

or they can do this by javascript codes like:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('ele').onclick = function(){};
</script>
```

And usually there are so many codes here so that it's sometimes difficult for us to identify which event function are called after the element event is triggered.

So my question is: is there any method or plug-in can help to identify the next running javascript statement or function entry point after one element event is triggered?

Comment: If you need debugging and use Firefox, firebug may help you.

Comment: Yes, in the firebug, I can set the break point in the codes. But my problem is that I don't know which function will be called if I click some element to trigger the event function. I just want to find the exact called function when I trigger the event. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you could do is, define a function that will grasp all events assigned to each type of elements and show them somewhere on the page(preferably at the bottom). To trigger that, function you may add a button which should be clicked.

Of course, all this must be done in debugging state and you would certainly want to remove the button and the display panel when releasing the App.

We used to do this for our project, may not be elegant but it does serve the purpose.

Comment: Thanks. My problem is that I don't own this web page...... The scenario is when I get in a web site, and I click one element, I want to know which function is called? How can I trace that function?

Comment: Not sure if such a comprehensive tool exists, but you can do the same with Firebug. Write the script in firebug and it will give you information for the current page state.

Answer (score 0):

There's no code that "emulates" the debugging of plugins like Firebug - however in case of "simple" onclick function simple `alert` will just show it:

```
var element = document.getElementById('ele');
alert(element.onclick);
```

And to programmatically trigger it:

```
element.onclick();
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. In fact, sometimes I am not the page programmer. This means when I come to a website, I found that when I click one element there will be something wonderful showing. So I want to know what function is called when I click the element. Is there any method or tool for this? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, Firebug. I'm not using it much but from what I remember I'm sure you can see the exact code being executed and even set break points.

Comment: Thanks! I will investigate the Firebug.